# Not able to connect to my aws ec2 instance using ubuntu terminal

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, amazon-ec2, putty

I am not able to connect to my ec2 instance using ubuntu terminal by ssh.
I was able to connect to my instance before using same .pem file and following the same process. but now it shows Connection closed by 52.76.178.207 every time.

Also i am able to connect to my instance using putty for linux and using the .ppk file generated by same .pem used in above process.

Also I am able to connect to my instance using ssh for first time if I reboot my instance. But second time I get connection refused.
Same thing happens with filezilla I am able to upload files first time after rebooting the instance but not after that.

One more weird thing is happening i.e i am able to see my directory structure in filezilla but not able to upload any file using filezilla.

Thanks for the help

Comment: did u check your firewall ?try to figure the ports in/out acceptance on the instances you are connecting..........

Comment: I am using Ubuntu to connect. And all the ports are open of instance. Also I am able to connect using putty but not able to connect using ssh

Comment: ubuntu has also one fire wall option you need to add the port numbers your instances you are connecting .......just search firewall and figure it up

Comment: if possible post the error so it will be more helpful to answer....

Comment: Connection closed by 52.76.178.207. is the only error I am getting while connecting through Ubuntu terminal using Ssh. one more thing I forgot to mention whenever I reboot my instance I am able to connect first time but not after that. Ssh port 22 is open of ec2 instance

Comment: your problem is either due to server load or else you should check the `/etc/hosts.allow` file `root@host # grep sshd /etc/hosts.allow
sshd: ALL`

Comment: My CPU usage is 5%. And I am able to connect using putty and also first time after rebooting my instance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112587/discussion-between-john-ankanna-and-vaibhav-ajay-gupta).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help @John Ankanna.

I still don't know what the problem is but below line fixes the problem.

echo 2 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_mtu_probing